# Where can I collaborate with my friend on source code in real time?

Tags: website, collaboration, source-code

I mean, other than a conference room :)

Using google docs, I can upload any kind of file and view it with other people, watch them edit it in real time, with a live chat happening in the same window. This is awesome.

How can I do the same thing with source code? I'm looking for a web application where I can upload source files that will be displayed in some kind of editor, with syntax highlighting, and allow others to view it and edit it in real time. Preferably with a live chat also, but not necessary. Does anybody know where I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/

Answer (score 2):

[Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/)

Comment: my friend can't seem to get it to work on his mac... Is there no online way to do this?

Comment: I've not seen anything online for this, but I've not looked.

Comment: well then, perhaps it's time for me to write one :)

Answer (score 2):

I have had success with VNC and similar desktop-sharing tools before (such as Webex, etc). The advantage with this over an online collaboration tool is that you can use your everyday development environment, just like you do when you are working alone or pair programming in person.

Pair that with a voice or video chat (such as skype or an old-fashioned telephone call), and you should be able to pair-program pretty effectively.

Answer (score 1):

I have used moonedit before, although I think its a little dated:

http://moonedit.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows then I'd highly recommend trying out 
[Microsoft SharedView](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=95af94ba-755e-4039-9038-63005ee9d33a&displaylang=en). I also found this via Scott Hanselman's blog post [Knowing When to Ask for Help - Microsoft SharedView](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/KnowingWhenToAskForHelpMicrosoftSharedView.aspx).

Comment: I am running windows but my friend is running osx

Comment: If there is only one 'editor' you could try Skype screen sharing (http://www.skype.com/intl/en/features/allfeatures/screensharing/) which is cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would use a combination of ssh, Gnu Screen, and vim. I would open a ssh session to a shared instance of screen which is a terminal multiplexer. You can use that to open multiple virtual terminals and be able to copy/paste between them and still both be able to see what each person is doing. I would use vim for the editor as that is what I normally use. It has has syntax highlighting, and amongst many other features, it is nice to be able to run the make command from inside of your editor.

An advantage here would be the ability to see the working environment and open multiple source files as needed. You would also be able to work on separate files and switch back and forth independently of each other.